# Application doesn´t adapt to the screen

Tags: android

I made an application in layout-normal. When I test it in a 5" screen I realized it didn't fit. I redo the layouts in layout-large, I added various densities and I made the declaration in the manifest and test it in the phone but still doesn't fit. However in the emulator it suits. What could be happening?

Attached one of the layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="480dp"
    android:layout_height="728dp"
    android:background="@drawable/note2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
        android:text="Productos:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        android:background="@drawable/escoba"
        android:onClick="VaciarLista"
        android:text="Vaciar" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_1"
        android:layout_width="430dp"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And a part of the Manifest:

```
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.proyecto"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
 <supports-screens
android:resizeable="true"
android:smallScreens="false"
android:normalScreens="true"                  
android:largeScreens="true"                  
android:xlargeScreens="false"
android:anyDensity="true"/> 
<application ...
```

Comment: layout-large is for tablets, afaik. So it has no impact on a 5" phone. Can't you post your layout code here?

Comment: tried match_parent rather than wrap_content ? as what happening to you is a normal result for assigning a fixed sizes like 480dp & 728dp to the main layout in your activity-layout

Comment: Yes, I've tried both and still don't work

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you specified a fixed size in the layout ? It would be useful if you could at least provide us with the layout content.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You should not used fixed `width` and `height` in your top group layouts

Comment: Tried putting with wrap_content, but is not adapted to the screen, leave me a white border.

Comment: Use match_parent for the width. Also, it's not a good practice to put a ListView in a ScrollView. You can put a header to your ListView instead.

Comment: You're right, The ScrollView isn't necesary. Regarding the background image it still doesn't adapt. And I'm thinking it may be due to the size of the image.

Comment: I retested on the phone with the settings and still not working, I don't Know what can occur.

Comment: don't use 'wrap_content' (that will be as small as necessary to 'wrap the content'. Use fill_parent instead. Then you should certainly see a difference.